# Why does using a higher Loop Count improve site performance in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

I've noticed that when load testing with JMeter, if I do a single loop I get a fairly long average time for my test.  If I have say a [Loop Count](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) of 10, my average time peaks early on and then drops way down.  For example if I setup a test on a simple get request for a page with the following settings:

```
Number of Threads (users): 500
Ramp-up Period(in seconds): 5
Loop Count: 1
```

My average time is about 4 seconds.  If I change it to 10 loops:

```
Number of Threads (users): 500
Ramp-up Period(in seconds): 5
Loop Count: 10
```

I get an average time of 1.4 seconds.

Apache's documentation states that the Loop Count is:

> The number of times the subelements of this controller will be
>   iterated each time through a test run.

Is it possible that this means the first request will actually do something on the server and the subsequent 9 requests will be pulling from cache?

How exactly is the `Loop Count` being used that would cause the results I'm seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Remaining 9 requests must be pulling from cache.

Loop controller is simple loop executor doing nothing magic inside.
Improved performance is because of use of cached results on server.

If you want one thing you can try, use the loop controller but use different substituted parameters so that every 
time different requests will be sent to server (I know that loop controller is for repeating same values, but this is just to confirm the effect of caching).
then compare the results.

I hope this clears the doubt :)